# Wamp: imported site using root links (/link) goes to localhost/ instead of localhost/projectname/

Tags: hyperlink, directory, wamp, document-root

I recently imported a live site to my local machine which runs wamp. The imported site uses root links, `/link`, which is fine, but it breaks the wordpress theme because it looks for `/localhost/` over `/localhost/projectname/`.

What can I do for it to recognize the project name in its linking? virtual hosts, aliases? Any help would be appreciated.